# PHP MySQL Left Join also using WHERE x IN y

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get the following SQL to work:

```
SELECT user.id,
       user.firstname,
       user.surname,
       user.gender,
       user.username,
       user.school_name,
       user.grade,
       user.vehicle,
       user.price,
       COUNT(student_reviews.userid) as reviews
 FROM user
 LEFT JOIN student_reviews ON student_reviews.userid = user.id
 WHERE user.id IN ($results)
 GROUP BY (student_reviews.userid)
```

The $results variable I'm passing in is '2,13,1'.

I only ever seem to get the first row back. It was working until I changed it to a left join to accommodate users that don't have any reviews.

I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just stumped.

Thanks

**Update**

It appears that when adding COUNT() or GROUP BY to the query, it only returns one result. It works until the COUNT() function is added

Comment: Do you mean `$results` is actually a string containing comma separated values, or a list of comma separated values?

Comment: $results is a string containing csv's. It's generated from another method in the class which is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are grouping by the column which can be null: student_reviews.userid (it's evaluated to null by left join for users without reviews). You should be grouping by user.id, and then you should get count zero for users without reviews. 
I'm guessing that the user you are getting as a single result has at least 1 review, while others have none.

Comment: hehe,  i actually posted this same solution 2 hours ago, but deleted my post when i saw that acmatos posted the same thing a couple minutes before me. turns out i didn't noticed that he grouped by "student_reviews.userid" but i grouped by "user.id". lesson learned: don't delete your own posts even if they seem like duplicates at first glance.

Comment: @Ben, I still can't tell why my solution didn't work for lethalMango. I did try switching `GROUP BY  p.aid` for `GROUP BY  a.id` in my SQL (@post update) and the result was exactly the same. :-)

Comment: @acmatos, I'm not sure. Without having the data and database in front of me, it's hard to visualize it clearly. What happens if you add another user (besides admin) to your test tables that also has no posts? Does a group on the left-joined table still return the expected results?

Comment: @Ben, exactly as expected. Another user with 0 posts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a subquery to get the number of reviews?

```
SELECT user.id,
       user.firstname,
       user.surname,
       user.gender,
       user.username,
       user.school_name,
       user.grade,
       user.vehicle,
       user.price,
       (
          SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student_reviews sr WHERE sr.userid = user.id
       ) as reviews
  FROM user
  WHERE user.id IN ($results)
```

When solving similar problems I go this route, because left join + group by usually doesn't give me the kind of results I want.